# Passing array to Swagger block parameter via the UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, swagger

Is it possible to pass an array of items into a single parameter in swagger blocks using the UI?  I am using this in a ruby \ rails application.  The type of request is a GET.

I have a search API that takes a number of parameters.  All of these are single value with the exception of one, facilities.  This accepts an array of items and can be called with a URL similar to that shown below (the example below shows two values of 1 and 2 being passed).

```
http://localhost:3000/api/venues/search.json?facilities%5B%5D=1&facilities%5B%5D=2
```

My parameter is setup like this:

```
# INDEX (API)
swagger_path '/venues.json' do
  operation :get do
    parameter do
      key :name, :facilities
      key :in, :query
      key :description, 'Facilities.  This does not work.'
      key :type, :array
      key :required, false
    end
  end
end
```

When I pass an array as a parameter in swagger, EG [1] it generates the following URL to call the API:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/venues/search?facilities=%5B1%5D
```

Swagger seems to translate the "[1]" into the URI "%5B1%5D" and puts it as the value of the parameter which is what I would expect it to do.  I hoped that because I set it up as a type of "array" that it would know to set the parameter name to "facilities%5B%5D" each time for each element of the array.

I think I missing some definition around the array but can't find any documentation on swagger blocks that can help.

I have seen a post where someone had passed a comma separated string then had the API create an array to get around this.

All my single value parameter requests work as expected.

Appreciate any help or advice.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI is URL encoding the value that you put in there because there are some non-supported characters being used (the '[' and ']').  When a character in the URL is evaluated to not be a native character in the url then it will be encoded, sent to the web server, and the web server typically decodes it and hands it off to whatever pipeline you are using.  A list of valid characters can be found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

It seems like you are trying to reproduce how a post body handles arrays.  This might be cause some issues due to the url encoding issue.  Have you tried doing the following to specify an array?

- Example: GET /products?items=1&items=2&items=3&items=4

Some web servers and pipelines treat this as an array and when you attempt to access "items" it returns, in this case, 1, 2, 3, and 4.  Just a thought.

Comment: I tried splitting them out as you have done in but that doesn't work.  When the API receives the values then it only retains one of those  paramters.  E.G. .../api/venues/search.json?facilities=19&facilities=18 only uses the last values when I query the params received by the API: 
=> {"facilities"=>"18", "format"=>"json", "action"=>"search", "controller"=>"api/v1/venues"}

Comment: Hmm.  Well, another trick that I personally use is to pass in a comma delim list for the param.  I'm not sure if that is something you would be willing to consider, but as long as the array you are passing is a primitive type (i.e. not a json object or anything like that) it should work like a champ.  For example: GET /api/venues/search.json?facilities=18,19.  Then in your code you would need to break it out into an array to handle it.

Comment: I had considered that as an option, yes.  It wouldn't take much to change the code to accommodate this either.  It would have been useful to know if it is possible for the future, if not then I can at least change the way I write my API's to factor this in.  I may delve into the code behind swagger to see if I can work out how it deals with arrays as there might be something in there that helps.  Just need a free day to do it, which is the tricky part ;o)  Thanks for taking the time to reply Jerrod.  I'll leave this unanswered for now as the suggestion is a work around.